# Airflow - Task not stopping correctly when setting it to Failed state

Tags: python, sql, airflow, amazon-redshift

We have a task A inside a dag B, running a big Redshift query, that can take up to 3 hours to run.
For some business reason that task can be "killed" by an other task, to perform that, we are first detecting if a dag B is running, if it's the case, we are requesting the running tasks, in our case, it's task A most of the time. We are using `ti.set_state(State.FAILED)` to set the state to Failed. Ultimately, we are setting the full dag run to state Failed with `dag.set_state(DagRunState.FAILED)`

Theorically, the task run should kill the running query, close the session, and Redshift on it side should release the lock shortly after since the session is supposed to be terminated.

However, we can see in our "redshift lock viewer" that, not only the lock is not released, but the query is still running after the task as been set to Failed. We check that by requesting the table `STV_RECENTS` with the right PID.

We tried to use a SIGTERM handler, to gracefully perform `cursor.close()` but it's giving weird error, and Airflow has to use SIGKILL after a short period of time. Also we tried with

```
try:
  ... Do the query ...
finally:
  cursor.close()
```

But we end up with the same problem than the handler.

Is there a way to gracefully kill the task and be sure the lock is released ?

Comment: Get the PID and use `select pg_terminate_backend(pid)` and confirm it returns 1

Comment: I can't get the PID, the last thing I run before it potentially fail is the `cursor.execute(...)`

Comment: You said you can still see it in the sys view, so why can't you get it?

Comment: We had a similar scenario. We have created an operator around the Redshift data hook. Under `on_kill` we have something like`hook.conn.cancel_statement(id)` which cancels the query on redshift when the task is killed.